# Navigation bar too large -- unnecessary room above; text "scrunched"

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

The navigation bar on my initial view controller is larger than the nav bars on all my other view controllers. In IB, my bar button item and title are distorted; and on the simulator, the bar simply looks too big.

When I transition between views, the bar visibly shrinks.

What's up?

[image]